# High Level OpenGL Library with PBO support

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, gpgpu

I want to do some image processing on the GPU and I'm looking for an appropriate library to use. The operations I want to do are: scaling, composition, color space transforms and translations.

I have considered OpenCL and CUDA but I believe that OpenGL is more appropriate as most of the operations required are already (directly or indirectly) implemented in OpenGL.

I have already successfully implemented the functionality needed using OpenGL, but I'd like to use a high level third party OpenGL library in order to improve reliability and maintainability.

However, all high level OpenGL libraries I have found so far do not make use of PBOs for fast transfers between device and host and vice-versa.

So far I have looked at [Shallows](http://shallows.sourceforge.net/) (no pbo, not maintained?) and [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (no pbo, maintained).

I'm looking for suggestions on appropriate tools for implementing simple image processing which can be easily maintained.

Comment: Implementing PBO texture uploads on your own would not be difficult if those libraries give you access to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt can do it, but it is a rather vast collection of libraries if you just want one thing out of it...

Comment: Yea, QT is a bit of a big dependency.